# Playing multiple audio files in Android

Tags: android, audio, media-player

I think I should know this, but my mind has gone blank. I'm making an app that has a few hundred small sound files and I want it to play a certain file dependent on a String I pass to the function. Where I hit the brick wall is getting the resId of the sound file.

I am using this code:

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.sound_file_1);
mp.start();
```

Gotten from here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/index.html

All I need is some help passing in a variable resId. Can anyone give me a hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `getResources().getIdentifier()` to convert the `String` into a resource ID. Please cache the result, as this lookup is done using reflection and therefore is a bit expensive in terms of CPU.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have been trying to use this method (unsure of whether or not it was right). Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Do you know how I can access the Res folder? I've tried with and without package names but I have had no luck. Thanks again

Comment: @TehGoose: I do not know what you mean by "access the Res folder", sorry.

Comment: Thank you. I have gotten it using the method you said. The problem was that I had stored my audio file in R.raw, and I couldn't seem to use the file while it's there. I was just using the method wrong. Thanks